# Solving homogeneous differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+8y^2}{3xy}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation. Use the fact that the given equation is homogeneous
>   $$
> \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+8y^2}{3xy}
> $$

First I multiply the right side by
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}
$$
Then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1+\frac{8y^2}{x^2}}{\frac{3y}{x}}
$$
$$
Let: v=\frac{y}{x}
$$ $$
\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}
$$
Then substitute
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1+v^2}{3v}$$
$$
\frac{1+v^2}{3v}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$$

How do I find the solution from here?

Comment: you missed a $8$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

First a slight miscalculation (you **missed** the $8$) on your part, it should be:

$$
\frac{1+8v^2}{3v}=v+x\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

After this just separate the variables and integrate:

$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\int \frac{3v\ \mathrm{d}v}{(1+5v^2)}$$

Can you proceed?

### Update:

To help you remove your confusion I have written down the remaining steps:

$$\frac{10}{3}\ln(xc)=\ln\left(1+5\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 \right)$$

$$\ln\left((xc)^{\frac{10}{3}}\right)=\ln\left(1+5\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 \right)$$

$$\frac 15 cx^{\frac{10}{3}}-\frac 15=\frac{y^2}{x^2}$$

$$\frac 15 cx^{\frac{10}{3}} \cdot x^2-\frac {x^2}{5}=y^2$$

$$\implies y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{cx^{\frac{16}{3}}}{5}-\frac {x^2}{5}}$$

$$\implies y=\pm \sqrt{c_1x^{\frac{16}{3}}-\frac {x^2}{5}}$$

Comment: I need help with this step

Comment: @Doldrums Let me know what you don't understand. The  LHS ($x$) is a simple $\log$ function and it's the same for RHS ($v$), except for the fact that you first have to use substitution.

Comment: I integrated to get 3/10 ln (1+5v^2)=ln(x) +c, but have trouble getting the equation in terms of v

Comment: @Doldrums Good job! You have done everything. All you need to do now is resubstitute $v=\frac{y}{x}$ in your equation, also you can simply write your constant $C$ as $\ln(C)$ and simplify.

Comment: How do I simplify the ln expressions easily

Comment: @Doldrums You can use two properties of logarithmic functions:
$$\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$$ and
$$n\ln(m)=\ln(m^n)$$
After you use this take exponential (anti-$\ln$) of both sides to remove $\ln$.

Comment: I got y=sqrt((cx^(10/3)-x)/5)

Comment: @Doldrums It's almost correct. You missed a small part it would be $\frac {x^2}{5}$ instead of $\frac {x}{5}$.

Comment: would it be x^10/3 or x^16/3

Comment: @Doldrums My apologies. It's actually $x^{16/2}$. I recalculated everything and got that. I suppose you are making a mistake when adding powers of $x$ note that : $$x^{10/3}*x^2=x^{16/3}$$

Comment: @Doldrums Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83229/discussion-between-paulplusx-and-doldrums).